# Error при установке sass

Tags: ruby, sass

Здравствуйте!

Необходимо установить Sass на Windows 8.1.  
Скачал и установил Ruby.
При установке Sass (по команде gem install sass) в окне терминала появилась такая ошибка:

> ERROR: Could not find a valid gem
> 'sass' (>=0), here is why: Unable to
> download data from
> https://rubygems.org/ - SSL connect 
> returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
> server certificate B: sertificate
> verify failed 
> (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Как устранить ошибку и установить Sass?  
Спасибо.

Comment: Прямо так и написано, "sertificate"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема с сертификатами. Варианта два: Скачать и прикрутить сертификат или отключить проверку.

Вот здесь описаны причины и решения:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat

http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550